# Connect to AWS Redshift using awswrangler

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-data-wrangler

```
import awswrangler as wr
con = wr.redshift.connect("MY_GLUE_CONNECTION")
```

What would be the value of "MY_GLUE_CONNECTION"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [to create a Glue connections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-connections.html) with unique name in the AWS console first

Let's give it a name **test_1**

[image]

then you can just pass this name to awswrangler

```py
import awswrangler as wr
con = wr.redshift.connect("test_1")
with con.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT 1;")
    print(cursor.fetchall())
    con.close()
```

and it will be working without any further steps if you have **aws cli** installed and authenticated. The trick here is the [boto3 auth mechanism](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html) used by awswrangler. awswrangler uses [boto3 in `awswrangler.redshift.connect()` method](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.0/stubs/awswrangler.redshift.connect.html) with the following note - *boto3_session (boto3.Session(), optional) – Boto3 Session. The default boto3 session will be used if boto3_session receive None.* So, in fact **boto3_session** is always used, but by being optional its use might be shadowed from you. With aws cli installed it will check `~/.aws/credentials` && `~/.aws/config` and will authenticate based on these files.
Another option is to initiate boto3 session in your code and pass it directly to your method.

```py
import awswrangler as wr
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN
)

con = wr.redshift.connect("test_1", boto3_session=session)
with con.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT 1;")
    print(cursor.fetchall())
    con.close()
```